# How to use Web parts in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i use web parts for performing drag and drops ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck.aspx) for ASP.NET WebParts. This is the opening article containing all the links to subsequent chapters to help you further understand and implement the WebParts into an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

There are also books dedicated to web parts, e.g. [ASP.NET 2.0 Web Parts in Action: Building Dynamic Web Portals](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781932394771) (APress).